# Concatenate JSON and Index variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

There is an input field, Which has name `metadata.country`. The functionality is to get the name and split than make those index in square brackets `['metadata']['country']`. I want to concatenate JSON and Index variables to get the country.The issue is when I try to join, it return [object Object].

**Code:**

```
//Input Fields (Html)
<input id="dataX" name="metadata.country">
<input id="dataY" name="metadata.city">

//Get ID
var inputField_Name = document.getElementById("dataX").attr['name'];

//JSON Data
var json = {name:"John",metadata:{country:"USA",city:"newyork"}};

//Split by dot
var targetName = inputField_Name.split('.');

//Convert them into square brackets
let copy='';

targetName.map(function(key, index) {
  copy +="['"+key+"']";

});

//Response copy: ['metadata']['country']
console.log(json + copy);
//Response:  [object Object]['metadata']['country']
```

Expected Response:
**"USA"**

**//Don't want this method:**

```
json [1];
```

Comment: What is teh expected output?

Comment: It won't return [object Object]. It should return `[object Object]1` because of implicit casting to string.

Comment: what you are trying to achive ? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @Tethys0 you are right!! but I want this output `{name:"John",country:"USA"}['1']`

Comment: @TahaFarooqui What are you trying to achieve after getting that output? See, you can have any output by doing manipulation, but there should be a why appended to every question right? So.. Why?

Comment: @Tethys0 I have update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet will help you find out the data from the object. Hope this helps

```js
var inputField_Name = "metadata.country"

var json = {name:"John",metadata:{country:"USA"}};

var targetName = inputField_Name.split('.');

let copy='';

const data = targetName.reduce((result, targetKey) => result[targetKey] || {}, json)

console.log(data)
```

Below method can be used to update the value at the specified location without mutating the original object. you can get the data from the method and can use it to do `setState`.

```js
let updateValue = (dataObj, keys, updatedValue) => {
    let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
    let result = (keys ||[]).reduce((result, targetKey, index) => {
        if(index === targetName.length - 1){
            result[targetKey] = updatedValue;
            return result[targetKey]
        }

        return result[targetKey] || {}
    }, json)
    return json;
}

var inputField_Name = "metadata.country"
var json = {name:"John",metadata:{country:"USA"}};
var targetName = inputField_Name.split('.');

const updatedJsonObj = updateValue(json, targetName, "CANADA")

console.group("Updated JSON");
console.log(updatedJsonObj)
console.groupEnd()

console.group("Original JSON");
console.log(json)
console.groupEnd()
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. I updated the answer for a scenario where if one of the values of a key in between is either `undefined` or `null` or `not found`.

Comment: Currently we are getting value. Is it possible to change the value? country:"Canada" using `setState`, I am using react.

Comment: Instead of doing `setState` inside reduce, I would suggest to return the object with updated value and then once the object is returned, then do `setState`.

Comment: Have updated my snippet to update the value at the desired location without mutating the original array. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to use `setState` code dynamically. It means currently, it only work on single item. Now I have multiple json objects `var json = [{id:"1",name:"John",metadata:{country:"USA"}},{id:"2",name:"Peter",metadata:{country:"Africa"}}];
` what logic should I use ?

Comment: You can just call the same method by looping that array. For eg.` var json = [{id:"1",name:"John",metadata:{country:"USA"}},{id:"2",name:"Peter",metadata:{country:"Africa"}}]` in order to apply the same function you can call like `let updatedArray = json.map(dataObj => updateValue(dataObj, targetName, "CANADA"))`. And in the end `updatedArray` can be used for updating the state.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```js
JSON.stringify(json) + JSON.stringify(index)
```

```js
var json = {name:"John",country:"USA"};
var index= ['1'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(json) + JSON.stringify(index));
```

Comment: as you can see, It added extra quotes in response `{"name":"John","country":"USA"}["1"]` . Look at the name and country.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to map through you can directly get the value from the object.

```js
let inputField_Name = "metadata.country"
let json = {name:"John",metadata:{country:"USA"}};
let [meta, key] = inputField_Name.split('.');
let out= json[meta][key];
console.log(out)
```

Comment: it is not working, If the array is third dimensional `{name:"John",metadata:{country:{city:"USA"}}};`

Comment: please update what your object structure will be, it can be up to 100 level as well, but we cannot just assume, you must mention all the scenarios. also if you are getting the right response with a 2 level object you can write for `n` as well.